# Modals of obligation occuring in the past

Tags: modal-verbs, could

I made a question and now I'm confused which one is the correct form?

- She should've at least given me more information about our festival so I could be prepared for it better.
- She should've at least given me more information about our festival so I couldve been prepared for it better.

Comment: Was the festival in the past, present or future?

Comment: Both are things people say. It doesn't matter much which one; they mean the same.

Comment: First, you don't **make** a question in English — in this case you prepared or composed or constructed two versions of a question. The word **form** does not sound right, and indeed "which is correct?" is all that is needed.  I would also recommend that you write **should have** rather than **should've**, and never **couldve**. This suggests to me that you should be posting on our sister site SE English Language Learners, not here. There you will probably get advice on identifying clearly what tenses you are using, and then using the simplest possible (I could prepare, I could have prepared).